# Puppeteer $$evan and QuerySelector

Tags: puppeteer

I need to get the code and product's title. I tried this but it returns me 'Cannot read property 'innerText' of null"

**HTML**

```
 <th data-code="XXXXXX">
     <div>
      <div id="title"><span>Product title</span></div>
     </div>
    </th> 
    <th data-code="XXXXXX">
     <div>
      <div id="title"><span>Product title</span></div>
     </div>
    </th>
```

**Puppeeter**

```
 let table = await page.$$eval(
     'table th',
      divs => divs.map((div, index) => ({
        title: div.querySelector('#title').innerText,
        code: div.dataset.code
      })
    )
 );
```

Comment: The HTML code is bad. There cannot be multiple IDs in one HTML document. You can try to use `div div span` instead of `#title`.

Comment: I haven't ownership of the HTML code. I am writing a parser using Puppeteer.

Comment: So... Did you try what I've written?